# Deleting popup over popup

Tags: jquery

Though it isn't ideal, I came across a situation where I have to have a popup over a popup. However, whenever I try to close BOTH the popups, it forgets about the parents popup and doesn't close it. If I do

```
    $('#LoadRejectionPopup').dialog('close');
    $('#LoadRejectionSave').dialog('close')
```

It fails on second line because the parent popup is no longer a popup. I just want both to close whenever a user clicks okay in 'LoadRejectionPopup'. Again this isn't ideal method but it is REQUIRED.

Comment: What do you mean the parent popup is no longer a popup?

Comment: It says the parent popup is not initialized so I cannot call a .dialog('close') on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both popups should have the JQuery UI class of `.ui-dialog-content`.

Give this a try - it should close both (all) popups.

```
$(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");
```

Comment: @user5975648 Good to hear!

Comment: I cannot upvote you because I have less than 15 reps but will give you best answer when possible

Comment: @user5975648 No worries, just glad to help out :-)